# Who's exactly refer to the act of "confessing a secret" here?

Tags: reference

Who's exactly refer to the act of "confessing a secret" here?

> You are going to read one of a series of articles from *The Times* called *Family Secrets*, which are unsigned and use fictitious names, and in which **readers** of the newspaper **confess** a secret.

If I'm not wrong 'confess a secret' means 'admit a secret' or 'reveal a secret'.

So here, why the author wrote '**readers** confess a secret' instead of writing '**A member of those families** confess a secret'?

Comment: I think it's because these articles are written based on the secrets of the readers. I mean readers have sent their secrets and the newspaper has published these secrets (The newspaper has used fictitious names instead of real names of readers or lets say *senders of the secrets*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that *confess a secret* means "admit a secret" or "reveal a secret".

The reason that it says **readers** is that the specific people confessing secrets are readers of the newspaper, not just random members of the families.

Answer (score 1):

It means that people who are readers of the newspaper will send in their confessions, to be published in the newspaper. The sentence is giving you the extra information that the pieces will not be written by journalists, or the newspaper's regular writers, but by people who read it.

By the way, it does not say that they will not be confessing to "a crime" , just to a "secret".